# Exclude specific build variants

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the two default build types: debug / release and a couple of flavors: prod / dev.

Now I want to exclude the build variant dev-release, but keep all other possible combinations. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

### Variant filter

Use the variantFilter of the gradle android plugin to mark certain combinations as ignored. Here is an example from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#filter-variants) that works with flavor dimensions and shows how it can be used:

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {...}

  flavorDimensions "api", "mode"
  productFlavors {
    demo {...}
    full {...}
    minApi24 {...}
    minApi23 {...}
    minApi21 {...}
  }

  variantFilter { variant ->
      def names = variant.flavors*.name
      // To check for a certain build type, use variant.buildType.name == "<buildType>"
      if (names.contains("minApi21") && names.contains("demo")) {
          // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
          setIgnore(true)
      }
  }
}
```

As the comment says, you can also check the buildType like so:

```
android {
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name
        if(variant.buildType.name == 'release' && names.contains("myforbiddenflavor")) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me more about `android.variantFilter { variant ->`, like what type of object is `variant`?, or what params does `variantFilter` function accepts? Could you provide a link where I can find documentation for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TrungDQ, have a look at this document, under release 0.9.0: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: I saw that document before, that looks like a change log, not a full document, I have go around that page but could not find the full detail document anywhere. I wonder if it really exists on the internet. Could you help me with that? I am having a problem with gradle/android and I need the document for reference.

Comment: Sorry, I've looked around but I can't seem to find any other documentation on this right now. The best I give you is the commit where it was added: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/bb739b8f05c937b08fedddd7bf13050f222472d2

Comment: I've added an issue to add some documentation for it to the android team at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=131534

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I posted a question about the problem I am dealing with, if you have time please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299376/gradle-android-variantfilter-caused-build-fail-after-upgrade-to-gradle-2-2-1

Answer (score 16):

Using variant filters like others I found it was easiest to do this by comparing the variant name against a list of variants that I want to keep.

So in my `app/build.gradle` file I have something like:

```
android {
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def needed = variant.name in [
                'stagingQuickDebug',       // for development
                'stagingFullDebug',        // for debugging all configurations
                'stagingFullCandidate',    // for local builds before beta release
                'stagingFullRelease',      // for beta releases
                'productionFullCandidate', // for local builds before going public
                'productionFullRelease'    // for public releases
        ]
        variant.setIgnore(!needed)
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
        candidate.initWith(release)
    }
    flavorDimensions "server", "build"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "server"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", '"https://example-preprod.com/"'
        }
        production {
            dimension "server"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", '"https://example.com/"'
        }
        quick {
            dimension "build"
            minSdkVersion 21
            resConfigs("en", "xxhdpi")
        }
        full {
            dimension "build"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

When working with flavor dimensions try this one

```
variantFilter { variant ->
    def dim = variant.flavors.collectEntries {
        [(it.productFlavor.dimension): it.productFlavor.name]
    }

    if (dim.dimensionOne == 'paid' && dim.dimensionSecond == 'someVal') {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked very well for build tools version - 23.0.2

Comment: Love this solution. It's much easier to use dimension name instead of `getFlavors().get(0)`.

Answer (score 14):

If you use **flavor dimensions** do this:

```
flavorDimensions "device", "server"

productFlavors {
    emulator {
        dimension = "device"
    }
    phone {
        dimension = "device"
    }
    staging {
        dimension = "server"
    }
    production {
        dimension = "server"
    }
}

android.variantFilter { variant ->
    def device = variant.getFlavors().get(0).name
    def server = variant.getFlavors().get(1).name
    def isRelease = variant.buildType.name.equals('release')
    def isDebug = variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')

    // Disable emulatorProductionRelease build variant
    if (device.equals('emulator') && server.equals('production') && isRelease) {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

It's easy to read and you can target specific build variants.

Answer (score 5):

The solutions here didn't work for me - I run into [this post](https://kousenit.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/excluding-gradle-tasks-with-a-name-pattern/) and added this to build.gradle in my app and it solved the issue for me

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
  graph.allTasks.findAll { it.name ==~ /.*MyVariant.*/ }*.enabled = false
}
```

This is what it does - waits for *gradle* to assemble the complete list of tasks to execute and then it marks all the tasks that match the name pattern as disabled

**NOTE** 
The match is exact - the expression above lets you match any task that has "MyVariant" somewhere in it's name and it is case sensitive

Answer (score 4):

One more simpler way

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.name == "qaDebug" || variant.name == "devRelease") {
        setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

Or if you place this code inside `android {}` closure, `android.` can be omitted

```
android {
    // Please always specify the reason for such filtering
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.name == "qaDebug" || variant.name == "devRelease") {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Please **always** put a meaningful comment for things like this.

**UPD**: For Kotlin Gradle DSL there is another way:

```
android {
    variantFilter {
        ignore = listOf("qaDebug", "devRelease").contains(name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @ade.se didn't work for me. But I've struggled a little, and written this, that works great:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

variantFilter { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name.equals('debug') || variant.buildType.name.equals('release')) {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fewlaps.quitnow"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 35
    versionName "1.35"
}
```

The code you have to add is the *variantFilter* one, but I've pasted a little of the context to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

See Variant filter answer above.

**Old Answer:**

It's not possible at the moment, but it's something we want to add. Probably soon.

In the meantime you could disable the assemble task I think. Something like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
   if ("devRelease".equals(variant.name)) {
       variant.assembleTask.enabled = false
   }
}
```

Comment: Any news on this? The combinations explode quickly, and whenever you run unit tests in Android Studio via the Gradle executor, it first assembles *all* build variants...

Comment: Use the variant filter explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Gradle's Kotlin DSL (i.e. build.gradle.kts), that would be:

```kotlin
variantFilter {
    ignore = buildType.name == "release" &&
             flavors.map { it.name }.contains("dev")
}
```