# Android build Types with different source sets

Tags: android, gradle

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23072096/2835239 and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

we have a posibility to use different source set for each flavor. 
This is great. But i have some code that the same for each flavor, but different for build types
i have source sets

```
-- main --- default source set 
-- flavor1
-- flavor2
```

I can create

```
-- main
--flavor1
--flavor1Release
--flavor1Debug
--flavor2
--flavor2Release
--flavor2Debug
```

but i can't create

```
-- main
-- mainRelease
-- mainDebug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mainRelease` is called `release`, and `mainDebug` is called `debug`. This is covered in [the first answer that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068315/different-drawable-based-on-build-variant-in-gradle/23072096#23072096).

IOW, to have build-type-specific variations of the `main` sourceset, you use a sourceset that is the name of the build type (`release`, `debug`, and any custom ones that you create).