# how can i make different apk that have specific image only in android in a single project?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, apk, android-productflavors

i am making a project.in that i am using 90 images for different purpose.i want to make a build that have only specific 30 images not 90.and other build have another 30 images. so i want that i have one project. but make different build that have specific images only. because i don't want to make apk that have 90 images.and i also don't want that i should make 3 different project. so this is possible in android ??

this is my Manifest.XML :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hoptheque">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".HopTheQue"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBWKrnd8g50GJztCbAPi-cQF60QDy0DxYo" />

        <!-- AIzaSyBWKrnd8g50GJztCbAPi-cQF60QDy0DxYo -->

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SponsorshipActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CareerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TourActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExperienceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactInfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventActivityTwo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BookTicketActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventActivityThird"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventActivityFourth"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventActivityOne"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventGallaryActivity"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentStatusBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name=".utils.LocationUpdateService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name=".utils.LocationStatusService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AddTicketInfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TicketListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentIntegrationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchEventResultActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CommonPageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyTicketActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyEventActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".EventTicketListActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So anybody have idea how can i do this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different drawable based on build variant in Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068315/different-drawable-based-on-build-variant-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with the help of android flavours
Check here [Android Flavours](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)