# Android app flavors to include certain files in output APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Is there a way in Android Studio build process to include certain drawables or any other files for that matter in the final build/apk based on flavors. What I have is an application that extends to a number of sub applications which have increased in part because of the free and pro versions. Different "flavors" contain different drawables and data files. It is mainly drawables that I would like to isolate for different flavors because there are a lot and the app would be way too big to contain all of them in one project built with flavors.

This is how far I got with research:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

All versions of my app share the same code and I would just like to isolate the data and images. I think flavors would be a perfect solution if I can get around the drawables build.

Example current project structure:

```
test.app1.pro
--src
--res
---drawables
---raw
...ect

test.app1.free
--src
--res
---drawables
---raw
...ect

test.app2.pro
--src
--res
---drawables
---raw
...ect

test.app2.free
--src
--res
---drawables
---raw
...ect

test.app3.pro
--src
--res
---drawables
---raw
...ect

...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Android Studio source sets thanks to this:
[Different drawable based on build variant in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068315/different-drawable-based-on-build-variant-in-gradle)

and this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Creating build type and flavor specific source sets in android studio should resolve the problem I am trying to resolve.