# How configure a different buildType for a flavor with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have two different flavor's, **RQT** & **PRD**.
And for one of them, I want to disable proguard configuration (for **RQT**, disable *proguard* for **both** *buildTypes*).
Like add conditioning ? Is something like that is possible ?

```
android {
  ...
  flavorDimensions("server")
  productFlavors {
    rqt {
      dimension "server"
      applicationIdSuffix ".rqt"
    }
    prd {
      dimension "server"
      applicationIdSuffix ".prd"
    }
  }
  ...
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      (__if (flavor != RQT) then do proguard config...__)
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      proguardFile 'proguard-debug-project.txt'
    }
    release {
      (__if (flavor != RQT) then do proguard config...__)
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      proguardFile 'proguard-release-project.txt'
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create additional Build Types, e.g. `debugNoProguard`, `releaseNoProguard`, etc.

```
android {
  variantFilter { variant ->
    def needed = variant.name in [
      'rqtDebugNoProguard',
      'rqtReleaseNoProguard',       
      'prdDebug',       
      'prdRelease'
    ]

    variant.setIgnore(!needed)
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      proguardFile 'proguard-debug-project.txt'
    }

    debugNoProguard {
      debuggable true
      minifyEnabled false
      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

Then instead of building `rqtDebug` you would build the variant `rqtDebugNoProguard` or `prdDebugNoProguard` when you wanted to run a debug build without ProGuard.

Comment: Ok for adding Build Types, unfortunately this won't fit my requirements. I'm building with Jenkins and I don't have any admin right on it. It will build for each flavors, each buildTypes. I'm really looking for exclusion/condition to add in buildTypes.

Comment: In that case, you could use a [variant filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237263/1426565) with the above flavor/buildtype combinations.

Comment: I edited the original answer to include the relevant filter