# what is the way to better define variables in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I define a variable in order to add different plugins to project, but it seems not working at all.

```
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name
        println names

        if (names.contains("someFlavor")) {
            google_service = false
        }else{
            google_service = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by saying: "not working at all"? What is not working?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221868/exclude-specific-build-variants

Comment: the variable "google_service" is always true in my case